# Wordpress pagination issue with `new WP_Query();` while used within a page template

Tags: php, wordpress

### **Scenario**

I'm trying to understand where I have gone wrong with my loop in regards to using my pagination hook. I'm using the theme Understrap, with Understrap-child, and i've made no edits to the pre-built hook which can be found [here](https://github.com/understrap/understrap/blob/master/inc/pagination.php).

I've used this hook in the loop listed below, which resides in a page template file. However the pagination hook isn't being output? The rest of the loop however, working perfectly fine.

Here's the kicker, I've used exactly the same structure within my index.php file. and it works completely fine. Which is driving me to believe I may need to declare something, just not sure as to what that may be.

### **Question**

I'm wondering if while using a page template, and `new WP_Query();` would I need to declare any globals to get `$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;` to work?

### **Code in Question**

> **For reference** I've included my loop, though I'm pretty sure it's ok.

```
<div class="bg-light">
  <div class="container space-top-3 space-bottom-2">
    <div class="row">
      <?php
      $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
       $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'orderby' => 'post_date',
          'order' => 'desc',
          'perm' => 'readable',
          'show_post_views' => true,
          'posts_per_page' => 9,
          'paged' => $paged
      );

      $latestArticles = new WP_Query( $args );
      if( $latestArticles->have_posts() ):
         /* Start the Loop */
         while( $latestArticles->have_posts() ) : $latestArticles->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content-search', get_post_format() );
         endwhile;
      endif;?>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <!-- The pagination component (currently not being output. not sure why.) -->
        <?php understrap_pagination(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <!-- do nothing -->
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for all help, in advance.

**Edit-7/11/19:**

Tried passing `$latestArticles->max_num_pages` to `understrap_pagination();`as such `understrap_pagination($latestArticles->max_num_pages);`. - Still no luck. :|

Comment: There's exactly one check inside the hook that may prevent it from outputting, that's if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages <= 1 ). Have you tried setting `max_num_pages` to something greater than one?

Comment: Sorry, see updated question. :)

Comment: Yeah :) Also try commenting that check out in the source code to see if it causes the problem. This is the main suspect basically.

Comment: Commenting the section out showed now improvement sadly. All my digging is pushing me to believe that it's related to the fact that the hook is dependant on the main query parameters.

Comment: so it solves the issue?

Comment: Apologies, typo; I mean't 'Commenting the section out showed no improvement sadly.'

Comment: so what do you see inside  <div class="row mt-3"><div class="col-auto">? Just nothing? Or some code from the pagination plugin?

Comment: Nothing is output; `<div class="col-auto">` is empty...

Comment: this is weird because you should at least see the empty <nav> container. Are you sure that this page has posts and you're not editing a wrong file?

Comment: !00% Sure it's the right file... It is really bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pagination function relies upon `$wp_query->max_num_pages` (i.e. the max number of pages for *the main query*), so the function will not work with custom queries:

```php
function understrap_pagination( $args = array(), $class = 'pagination' ) {

    if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages <= 1 ) {
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

And while your approach does work, it's really not a good idea to alter the global `$wp_query` object because doing so is essentially the same as using `query_posts()` which is not recommended at all — you can see why so by checking the docs [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#more-information).

However, if you don't want to edit the pagination function (or create your own), then a less risky workaround to get the pagination works with your custom query, is by temporarily changing the — and **only the** — `$wp_query->max_num_pages`:

```php
$orig_max_num_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; // backup

// Change it just for the pagination.
// and $latestArticles is your custom WP_Query instance.
$wp_query->max_num_pages = $latestArticles->max_num_pages;

$paged = max( get_query_var( 'paged' ), get_query_var( 'page' ), 1 );
understrap_pagination( [
    'current' => $paged,
] );

$wp_query->max_num_pages = $orig_max_num_pages; // restore
```

[Sample Page template based on your original code](https://gist.github.com/5ally/dbe0d17656afa8f67bbafb0d984dcbc2).

#### A Better Practice: Copy/Edit the pagination *function*.

Since you're using a *child theme*, and that Understrap uses [`locate_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) to load the file ([`inc/pagination.php`](https://github.com/understrap/understrap/blob/master/inc/pagination.php)) which defines the pagination function, you can just copy the file to the child theme (`your-theme/inc/pagination.php`) and edit the function so that it works with custom `WP_Query` queries. *Or* since the function is pluggable (i.e. defined with a `if ( ! function_exists() )` block), you can just copy the code to your child theme's `functions.php` file.

1. You can use this modified function (which works well for me) or use it as a reference to create your own:

   ```php
   function understrap_pagination( $args = array(), $class = 'pagination' ) {

       $args = wp_parse_args(
           $args,
           array(
               'mid_size'           => 2,
               'prev_next'          => true,
               'prev_text'          => __( '&laquo;', 'understrap' ),
               'next_text'          => __( '&raquo;', 'understrap' ),
               'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation', 'understrap' ),
               'type'               => 'array',
               'current'            => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
               'total'              => $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages,
           )
       );

       // Nothing to paginate, so let's bail.
       if ( ! $links = paginate_links( $args ) ) {
           return;
       }

       ?>

       <nav aria-label="<?php echo $args['screen_reader_text']; ?>">

           <ul class="pagination">

               <?php
               foreach ( $links as $key => $link ) {
                   ?>
                   <li class="page-item <?php echo strpos( $link, 'current' ) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                       <?php echo str_replace( 'page-numbers', 'page-link', $link ); ?>
                   </li>
                   <?php
               }
               ?>

           </ul>

       </nav>

       <?php
   }
   ```
2. Then in your template, call the function like so:

   ```php
   $paged = max( get_query_var( 'paged' ), get_query_var( 'page' ), 1 );
   understrap_pagination( [
       'current' => $paged,
       'total'   => $latestArticles->max_num_pages,
   ] );
   ```

[Sample Page template based on your original code](https://gist.github.com/5ally/c76588e33f44d3281c34ea9039a94859).

#### `paged` vs `page`

`paged` and `page` are both the *number of the current page*, however:

- `paged` is used with archive-based requests/URLs such as category archives and search results pages. On these requests, `page` is not set by default. It should also be noted that `paged` is used with [`is_paged()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_paged/).
- `page` is used with singular requests/URLs such as single Post and Page pages. On these requests, `paged` is not set by default.

And the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Static_Front_Page) recommends the following approach to get the proper page number on singular requests/URLs:

```php
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
else { $paged = 1; }
```

Or simpler version: `$paged = max( get_query_var( 'paged' ), get_query_var( 'page' ), 1 );`

NB: That Codex article refers to static front Page, but the information also applies to any Pages/Posts.

---

And last but not least… with secondary `WP_Query` calls (like your `$latestArticles = new WP_Query( $args )`), you just need to call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) and no need to call `wp_reset_query()`. :)

Comment: You my dear, are a legend! Perfectly clarified and easy to understand, I've already implemented your answer and it's working like a charm! Thanks for the clarification. +1

Comment: Still it's a little annoying to now see how close I was with my original attempt. Haha!

Comment: I actually did wait for you to update your answer.. xD But anyway, I'm glad my answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to locate this post [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/paginate-custom-post-types/) by CSS-Tricks which outlines a method that nukes the current `$wp_query` variable and replaces it with a new instance of `WP_Query();`

**My loop now works as expected** however, I was under the impression that `$wp_query` is reserved, is that not correct? Is it safe to use this method?

My new loop looks like this;

```
<div class="bg-light">
  <div class="container space-top-3 space-bottom-2">
    <div class="row">
      <?php
            $temp = $wp_query; 
            $wp_query = null; 
            $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'order' => 'desc',
                'perm' => 'readable',
                'show_post_views' => true,
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
                'paged' => $paged
            ); ?>
      <?php $wp_query->query($args); ?>

      <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
      <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
      <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();  ?>
      <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content-search', get_post_format() ); ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <!-- The pagination component -->
        <?php understrap_pagination(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <!-- do nothing -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $wp_query = null; 
        $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone knows of a better approach I'd be interested in hearing it. Many thanks in advance. -B.

Comment: `wp_reset_query()` should do exactly that but cleaner

Comment: I'll need to read up on `wp_reset_query();` but if that is the case, somethings definitely wrong with the hook then. The loop as I suspected must be ok.